# Same class names on different libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In objective C I believed that it is never possible to use same class name for different classes(in .m files). Also xcode will through duplicate symbol error.

But in a recent project I found 2 different static libraries using same class names. And also project build and run succesful.

Why is it not showing duplicate symbol error? How can the developer know which library xcode references for that class ?

Comment: I believe it's possible to have the same name appear twice in two different static libraries without creating linker error.  But it can and does cause considerable confusion.  It's best avoided.

Comment: By default, the linker doesn't care unless you somehow force it to load everything from the various static libraries.  When it finds a match, it uses it without knowing whether it's what you really wanted.  If you used -ObjC or -all_load flags, I'd not be surprised if it complained…but I haven't tried it.